# Forcing WWW And HTTPS (SSL) In .htaccess -- Requiring Assistance

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have found a thousand other topics asking for help with this, but none of their solutions seem to work for some reason.

I just purchased SSL for my domain a couple of days ago because I am accepting credit/check cards on my site and I want my customers to feel and be secure.

Anyways, this is what my .htaccess file looks like at the moment:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-wow-accounts index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^sell-wow-accounts sell.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-khaccounts about.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^buy-sell-wow-accounts-faq faq.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^khaccounts-feedback feedback.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^payment-plan payment-plan.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^customer-login customer-login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^customer-center customer-center.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy privacy.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^buy-world-of-warcraft-wow-accounts/page-([0-9]+) listing.php?pageid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^buy-world-of-warcraft-wow-accounts listing.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^world-of-warcraft-wow-acc/([^/]*)\.html$ account.php?acc=$1 [NC]
```

What I want to do is force WWW if it is not already in the URL and ensure that HTTPS (SSL) is forced as well.  I have a ton of links out there to my site and most of them are just links like 'www.khaccounts.net', 'http://khaccounts.net', and 'khaccounts.net'.

I want to ensure that each of these different old links will be forced into having WWW and HTTPS. In order words, I want people to have the URL - 'https://www.khaccounts.net' no matter what URL they took to get to my site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right after your www rules add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Also, change your www rule to `https://` so that there aren't 2 redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're rewriting all of your urls to the root. Why don't you try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This does not work.  When I enter in 'khaccounts.net', it shows 'https://khaccounts.net//' in the URL and says that the page has a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these lines :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

With this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.khaccounts\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.khaccounts.net/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: That seems to do what I need, but the problem is that all it puts into the URL is https://www. -- It is missing the requested URL.

Comment: That's weird, the $1 is there to capture the requested url and pass it to the new url ... hmm ...

Comment: Yeah, all that is showing up is -- https:\\www. -- thats it.  I put https://www\.khaccounts\.net$1 as the rewrite rule and it gave me the right URL, but put me into a redirect loop.

Comment: Any other ideas Yazmat?  Is there something I could be missing that should be installed on my server?  I have mod_rewrite enabled and the SSL certificate works perfectly.

Comment: I can't figure out why, try enabling rewrite logs and see what is realy happening when doing a request, it may give you better ideas on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This works in showing the proper URL when khaccounts.net is hit, but still throws a redirect loop.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.khaccounts.net/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```